# Autocomplete not working on all editor on mac os

Tags: html, macos, editor

I'm using  OS X El capitan and i have problem with my code editor.
Autocomplete not working, popup dropdown does NOT show up.
I have tried in sublime text 2-3, atom, bracket, Xcode.
Press TAB is OK. But i want to show the popup dropdown.
Has anyone else experienced this or know what would have caused this? 
Please help me.
Tks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried pressing Ctrl + Space to bring up code complete?

Comment: it worked, but i want  automatic show popup.

Comment: Sorry I can't help much more, I only use Mac OS at work and we are still on Yosemite, I don't hear very many good things about upgrading to El Capitan :S

Comment: Have you tried this? https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/auto_complete.html